# Can't find documentation for these parameters inside "send mail"'s Request Payload

Tags: gmail-api

When anyone log into Gmail via any browser (i.e. not using email clients).. any action generates a Javascript request (or a series of Javascript requests).

Specifically, when you try to send an email a similar request will be generated (you can view it via developer tools):

```
{1: {3: 2}, 2: {1: [{1: "6",…}]}, 4: {2: 1, 3: "1605531970721", 4: 1, 5: 203}, 5: 2}
1: {3: 2}
1: "6"
2: {1: "thread-a:r7102655505722629369", 2: {14: {1: {1: "msg-a:r7097698051777609688",…}, 3: 1}}}
1: "thread-a:r7102655505722629369"
2: {1: 1, 2: "j.doe@somedomain.com", 3: "john doe", 10: "j.doe@somedomain.com"}
1: 1
2: "j.doe@somedomain.com"
3: "john doe"
10: "j.doe@somedomain.com"
3: [{1: 1, 2: "peter22@anotherdomain.com"}]
0: {1: 1, 2: "peter22@anotherdomain.com"}
8: "test subject"
9: {2: [{1: 0, 2: "<div dir="ltr">test</div>"}], 7: 1}
2: [{1: 0, 2: "<div dir="ltr">test</div>"}]
0: {1: 0, 2: "<div dir="ltr">test</div>"}
```

the request consists of key-value pairs.. the problem is the keys are not self-descriptive (i.e. just numbers).. and I tried to search everywhere.. even tried to open a case with Gsuite Support but they said they don't know about it as it belongs to the backend.

A similar request from Office365 has self-descriptive names (e.g. "MailboxType:ExternalMailbox" to indicate that the email is sent to external recipient).

Is there any documentation for what these parameters means? Or anyone know who to ask or where to open a case regarding this matter?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: @iansedano we're implementing a security control based on this payload.. in specific whether the email is sent to internal recipient (same domain) or external recipient.

Comment: Do you want to block the email or just have some data on it?